# Is it more efficient to use boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_read_some instead of boost::asio::async_read?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-asio

Is it better to use boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_read_some instead of boost::asio::async_read when it comes to high performance data throughput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::asio::async_read` is a composed operation, which is well described in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html)

> This operation is implemented in terms
>   of zero or more calls to the stream's
>   async_read_some function, and is known
>   as a composed operation. The program
>   must ensure that the stream performs
>   no other read operations (such as
>   async_read, the stream's
>   async_read_some function, or any other
>   composed operations that perform
>   reads) until this operation completes.

any performance conclusions should be based on empirical data depending on your application.

Comment: Does it being a composed operation imply that is is likely slower?

Comment: @nick, It probably just means its no better (or worse) than calling the same functions yourself.